# Problem with recursion, how should I control the values in this list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, linked-list, tree

I am trying to solve question no [1367 of Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/linked-list-in-binary-tree/)   and the idea that I have to solve this is that firstly I stored all the values of the elements in the Linked List into a list called target and then I am traversing the array and storing the elements. Whenever I match the first if condition in dfs it returns true and hence that becomes the ans.

[image]

Code

```
class Solution:
    def isSubPath(self, head: Optional[ListNode], root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        ll=[]
        node=head
        while node:
            ll.append(node.val)
            node=node.next
        def dfs(node,cur,target):
            print(f"a.{node} {cur} {target}")
            print()
            if len(cur)>=len(target):
                if cur[-len(target):]==target:
                    return True
            if not node:
                return False
            cur.append(node.val)
            print(f"1.{node.left} {cur} {target}")
            print()
            print(f"2.{node.right} {cur} {target}")
            return dfs(node.left,cur,target) or dfs(node.right,cur,target)
        return dfs(root,[],ll)
```

Now how i wanted this work is that intially the values that I am sending to dfs fucntion for the tree given above is `(1,[],[4,2,8])` from here both the if cases will fail hence we will have `[A]->return (4,[1],[4,2,8]) or (4,[1],[4,2,8])`(A is for identification). Now this will give rise to further recursions where let's 1st explore the left node. so then `(4,[1],[4,2,8]) gives rise to (None,[1,4],[4,2,8]) or (2,[1,4],[4,2,8])` now here since there is no left node that returns False and the right node becomes `(1,[1,4,2],[4,2,8]) or (None,[1,4,2],[4,2,8])` Here all conditions fail and we reach to the start of the recursion i.e., to step 'A'. Here the left part becomes `False` and now the right part. Here  is where I am having issues. If you understood how I want my code to work then you would realise that now I want my curr list to become `[1]->[1,4]->[1,4,2]->[1,4,2,6] and [1,4,2,8]` and since the list `[1,4,2,8] satisfies the condition curr[-len(target):]==target` we return True. But this is not happening. The current list is storing all the values from all the iterations i.e., by the end of the traversing on the left side, the value of curr is[1,4,2,1] and this curr is being passed to the right half and the same problem when it gets to [4,2,6] part, then it appends 8 which makes is [4,2,6,8] thus failing my code. I know my explanation can be quite terrible but please try reading it once again or execute my code with the print statements and y'll know the problem. How can I solve this. Pls help

Comment: You need to keep separate lists for your `curr` for left and right traversal. The `curr` list used will be modifed throughout the traversals because whenever you change `curr` it is a reference to the original list.

Comment: @AliasCartellano could you provide the code for that please, cuz this concept has been a problem for too long and I am not able to understand this specific thing using any existing explanation, so it would be really great if you could just provide that correct code showing the implementation.

Comment: The thing is that you are really asking for the solution to the code challenge, which is for you to find. If we answer with one little problem in your code, it will not be enough to make it work completely unless we give you a perfect solution. So this question will probably not get much attention.